How can i restart my program/go back to a particular line of code
I looked for a solution online and found a line of code that was supposedly meant to do what im trying to do os.execv(sys.argv[0], sys.argv) , but instead it just ends/closes/kills the script instead of restarting it, ive tried a bunch of different lines of code that i could find on google that were apparently meant to restart the script but none of them worked for various reasons i couldnt figure out.
this is my code:
import sys
import os
import time

formula = input("\n______________________________________________\nSelect your formula.\n______________________________________________\n1 = Area of circle.\n2 = Area of rectangle.\n3 = Weekly wages.\n4 = Add standard rate of VAT to a price.\n5 = 5 + 30 x 20 ÷ 10.\n6 = Cicumference of circle.\n______________________________________________\nTo avoid errors please only answer in numbers.\n______________________________________________\n\n")
if formula == "1":

    pi = 3.14159265
   
    r = float(input("\nWhat is the radius of the circle?\n\n"))
   
    area = pi * r * r
   
    print("\nThe area of your circle is",area,".\n\n")
   
    restart = input("\nRestart program?\n1 = Yes\n2 = No\n\n")

    while not restart.isdigit():
           restart = input("\nPlease only enter whole numbers.\n\n")
   
    if restart == "1":
        os.execv(sys.executable, 
         [sys.executable, os.path.join(sys.path[0], __file__)] + sys.argv[1:])
        
    else:
        print("\nGoodbye\n\n")
        time.sleep(1)

        
        sys.exit("Bye")
   

elif formula == "2":
    length = float(input("\nWhat is the length of the rectangle?\n\n"))
   
    width = float(input("\nAnd what is the width of the rectangle?\n\n"))
   
    area = length * width
   
    print("\nThe area of your rectangle is",area,".\n\n")
   
    restart = input("\nRestart program?\n1 = Yes\n2 = No\n\n")

    while not restart.isdigit():
           restart = input("\nPlease only enter whole numbers.\n\n")
   
    if restart == "1":
        os.execv(sys.executable, 
         [sys.executable, os.path.join(sys.path[0], __file__)] + sys.argv[1:])
       
    else:
        print("\nGoodbye\n\n")
        time.sleep(1)

        
        sys.exit("Bye")
   

elif formula == "3":
    hours = float(input("\nHow many hours did you work this week?\n\n"))
   
    wage = float(input("\nAnd what is your hourly rate?\n\n"))
   
    weeklywage = hours * wage
   
    print("\nYour weekly wage is",weeklywage,".\n\n")
   
    restart = input("\nRestart program?\n1 = Yes\n2 = No\n\n")

    while not restart.isdigit():
           restart = input("\nPlease only enter whole numbers.\n\n")
   
    if restart == "1":
        os.execv(sys.executable, 
         [sys.executable, os.path.join(sys.path[0], __file__)] + sys.argv[1:])
       
    else:
        print("\nGoodbye\n\n")
        time.sleep(1)

        
        sys.exit("Bye")
   

elif formula == "4":
    price = float(input("\nWhat is the price of the item before VAT?\n\n"))
   
    vat = price * 0.2
   
    total = price + vat
   
    print("\nThe total price of the item VAT included is",total,".")
   
    restart = input("\nRestart program?\n1 = Yes\n2 = No\n\n")

    while not restart.isdigit():
           restart = input("\nPlease only enter whole numbers.\n\n")
   
    if restart == "1":
        os.execv(sys.executable, 
         [sys.executable, os.path.join(sys.path[0], __file__)] + sys.argv[1:])
       
    else:
        print("\nGoodbye\n\n")
        time.sleep(1)

        
        sys.exit("Bye")
   
elif formula == "5":
    print("\n",5 + 30 * 20/10,"\n")
   
    restart = input("\nRestart program?\n1 = Yes\n2 = No\n\n")

    while not restart.isdigit():
           restart = input("\nPlease only enter whole numbers.\n\n")
   
    if restart == "1":
        os.execv(sys.executable, 
         [sys.executable, os.path.join(sys.path[0], __file__)] + sys.argv[1:])
       
    else:
        print("\nGoodbye\n\n")
        time.sleep(1)

        
        sys.exit("Bye")

elif formula == "6":
    pi = 3.14159265
   
    radius = float(input("\nWhat is the radius of the circle?\n\n"))
   
    circumference = 2 * 3.14159265 * radius
   
    print("The circumference of your circle is",circumference,".")
   
    restart = input("\nRestart program?\n1 = Yes\n2 = No\n\n")

    while not restart.isdigit():
           restart = input("\nPlease only enter whole numbers.\n\n")
   
    if restart == "1":
        os.execv(sys.executable, 
         [sys.executable, os.path.join(sys.path[0], __file__)] + sys.argv[1:])
       
    else:
        print("\nGoodbye\n\n")
        time.sleep(1)

        
        sys.exit("Bye")


else:
    print("\nThat is not a suitable option.")
   
    restart = input("\nRestart program?\n1 = Yes\n2 = No\n\n")

    while not restart.isdigit():
           restart = input("\nPlease only enter whole numbers.\n\n")

   
    if restart == "1":

        os.execv(sys.executable, 
         [sys.executable, os.path.join(sys.path[0], __file__)] + sys.argv[1:])
        
    else:
        print("\nGoodbye\n\n")
        time.sleep(1)

        
        sys.exit("Bye")


What do you mean go to a particular line of code? You want to pause the execution of the code at a certain line? You can use a debugger for that. Put a breakpoint in the line you want to pause and run the code in debug mode.

This is an XY problem – to "restart" the script, put everything in a function, and call the function at the start and again when you want to restart

Also notice that you are repeating a lot of things inside each conditional. You might want to refactor your code first. The restart thing should go inside a function and the processing of the formular option in another function.

How do i put the script into a function?

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions or google for "python functions tutorial"

check my answer on how to refactor your code into something more organized. Then I'd recommend you read the python documentation to get familiarized with the language first. Knowing what the language has to offer will make your code much better.
